# Avoid generating duplicating random number 

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

As per the module requirement file name length to be as 8 chars, for that to implement first 4 char `DDMM` and remaining 4 char trying to fetch the random numbers from the database by using function and view, the same what I am using in database I have pasted below:

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GenerateRandomNumbersLetters]
(
    @NumberOfCharacters TINYINT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(32)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 
    (
        SELECT LEFT(REPLACE([NewID], '-', ''), @NumberOfCharacters)
        FROM dbo.RetrieveNewID
    );
END
```

View:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[RetrieveNewID]
AS
    SELECT [NewID] = NEWID();
```

My query:

```
select  
   SUBSTRING(replace(convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 3), '/', ''), 1, 4) +  
   dbo.GenerateRandomNumbersLetters(4) as FileNamerandomNUM
```

Ex: `0907CCE7`

For every row it will provide a random number, but in one scenario recently the random generate duplicates, how can I avoid such scenarios also, kindly advice

Comment: I assume that there's no risk that you'll try to generate more that 65536 file names on a single day?

Comment: yeah, but i am wondering for one particular file it duplicates last four digits random number, can it possible to cross check while generating?

Comment: Why the requirement to generate a *random* sequence number for the file name? Why not use a simple sequential number scheme? You cannot answer anything 'security' since 4 digits is ridiculously small space for security concerns.

Comment: ok, can you give some tips to generate a simple sequential number scheme about for 4 Digits please, i will try and perform it,thanks for prompt reply

Answer (score 1):

There is a risk of 'value repeating' for random numbers especially if you take only the first four digit of a random number.

Instead of that , generate sequence numbers. to implement this you can create a table with structure

```
file_date | seq_no

Ex: 0907 | 1000
    0907 | 1001
```

then each time you want to get a file name, query against this table for the next sequence number

```
select max(seq_no)+1 from <table>
```